# How to enable pthreads in PHP 5.6.13 at CentOS 6.7?

Tags: php, pthreads

I have PHP 5.6.13 installed at CentOS 6.7 through IUS repositories. This is the output of `php -v` command:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2015 11:54:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

For install and enable `pthreads` I have follow this steps:

1. Search the proper packages:

   ```
   # yum search pthreads
   ================================= N/S Matched: pthreads ===============================
   mingw32-winpthreads-static.noarch : Static version of the MinGW Windows pthreads library
   mingw64-winpthreads-static.noarch : Static version of the MinGW Windows pthreads library
   php55u-pecl-pthreads-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package php55u-pecl-pthreads
   php56u-pecl-pthreads-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package php56u-pecl-pthreads
   mingw32-winpthreads.noarch : MinGW pthread library for the win32 target
   mingw64-winpthreads.noarch : MinGW pthread library for the win64 target
   openblas-threads.i686 : An optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2, pthreads version
   openblas-threads.x86_64 : An optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2, pthreads version
   php55u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64 : Threading API
   php56u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64 : Threading API
   ```
2. Install the package:

   ```
   #yum install php56u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64

   Resolving Dependencies
   --> Running transaction check
   ---> Package php56u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64 0:2.0.10-2.ius.el6 will be installed
   --> Finished Dependency Resolution

   Dependencies Resolved
   =======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
    Package                                                         Arch                                              Version                                                        Repository                                      Size
   =======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
   Installing:
    php56u-pecl-pthreads                                            x86_64                                            2.0.10-2.ius.el6                                               ius                                             71 k

   Transaction Summary
   =======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
   Install       1 Package(s)
   ```
3. Locate where the `.so` did go:

   ```
   #locate pthreads.so
   /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so
   ```
4. Enable at `/etc/php.ini` by trying each of the following lines:

   ```
   extension=pthreads.so
   extension=/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so
   zend_extension=pthreads.so
   zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so
   ```
5. Restarted Apache and find for the module

   ```
   # php -m | grep pthreads
   Failed loading /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so:  /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id
   ```

And all the time it fails with the message above. What I am doing wrong?

**Note:** I have notice by running `phpinfo()` that `Thread Safety` is disabled, do I need this enabled in order to properly load the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason there is two different Versions, the one you installed which cause a conflict with your PHP version. Mismatched compile options used with pthreads.so compared with those used to build PHP itself.

> php56u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64 0:2.0.10-2.ius.el6

You should remove and install everything from the same source/version.
That's only thing i could think of.

EDIT:
you could try this... [pthreads using php+zts rpms on centos](https://io.ofbeaton.com/2015/02/pthreads-phpzts-rpms-centos/)

Comment: You're wrong, there are two version of the same extension: `php55u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64` which is used for php5u (meaning PHP 5.5.x) and `php56u-pecl-pthreads.x86_64` which is used for php56u (PHP 5.6.x) the installed extension is the right one, so there is something I am missing here I just can't find it

Comment: Yes, you are part right, i was talkin about this particular number >0:2.0.10-2.ius.el6

Comment: I'm not following you, what's the problem with that number and PHP version?

Comment: Your PHP Version is **PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2015 11:54:03)** But that PHP built is not compatible with your **pthreads** For example: PHP from REMI and installed **pthreads** from IUS, you will get that error...  It is an extreme example...

Comment: That's not the problem either, both PHP and the extension are installed from the same repository IUS: [php56u-pecl-pthreads](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/repoview/php56u-pecl-pthreads.html), [php56u-common](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/repoview/php56u-common.html)

Comment: Ahhhhh waits you might be right, description said it's ported from REMI repository, perhaps that's where the issue is. also reads that needs ZTS mode enabled :-/ I'm confused, any advice?